# Export a complete list of sharing created into SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, external-users

I need to export from SharePoint Online (365) a complete list of all links of sharing created in the past. I need it to verify if external users can access to some files on SharePoint.

I already tried the command:

```
$SiteCollections = Get-SPOSite https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/ -Limit All
foreach ($site in $SiteCollections)
{
    $ExternalUsers += Get-SPOUser -Limit All -Site $site.Url | Where {$_.LoginName -like "*urn:spo:guest*" -or $_.LoginName -like "*"} | Select DisplayName,LoginName,@{Name = "Url"; Expression = { $site.url }}
}
$ExternalUsers | Export-Csv -Path "C:\PowerShell\ExternalUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But this extracted only the external users that can access to my "home link" https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/ (I suppose… but maybe I'm wrong). I need all links for sharings generated, not only my principal site path… is it possible to do so? I don't know all the links generated, so I need a list of it with users (internal and external) which can access it.

Someone can help me please? I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

No help to your issue, but some hints on coding:

- using `$ExternalUsers +=` in a ForEach is very inefficient as it rebuilds the array variable on every iteration
- coding one endless line makes it hard to read and discover flaws (here the 2nd where clause includes the 1st one)
- whenever PowerShell expects a continuation you may insert line breaks (without a trailing backtick ` ) like after a `|` or `,` or operator `-or`

So this should work:

```
$SiteCollections  = Get-SPOSite https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/ -Limit All

$ExternalUsers = ForEach ($Site in $SiteCollections){
    Get-SPOUser -Limit All -Site $site.Url | 
      Where-Object {$_.LoginName -like "*urn:spo:guest*" -or 
                    $_.LoginName -like "*"} | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCutomObject]@{
          DisplayName = $_.DisplayName
          LoginName   = $_.LoginName
          Url         = $site.url
        }
    }
}
$ExternalUsers | Export-Csv -Path "C:\PowerShell\ExternalUsers.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```